# Sharrre - Facebook data-text and data-url not showing on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, jquery-plugins

Earlier I used Sharrre just for one button set per page and it worked just fine. However, I had to change that and now I have 4 sets of buttons and the data-text and data-url values are not showing in the facebook popup - instead it loads the text from the actual linked page which wouldn't bother me so much if it wouldn't come from a hidden form showing "Contact usNameEmail.." etc. It works with twitter and shows first the data-text value and then data-url, just like it should.

I'm using a system almost like the Sharrre example 2 (http://sharrre.com/example2.html) and my codes are now:

HTML

```
<div class="share-buttons" data-url="MY URL" data-text="MY TEXT"></div>
```

and the jQuery

```
$('.share-buttons').each(function() {
    $(this).sharrre({
        share: {
            twitter: true,
            facebook: true
        },
        template: '<div class="share-icon-holder"><a href="#" class="facebook"><img src="fb.png" /></a><a href="#" class="twitter"><img src="twitter.png" /></a></div><div class="share-text"><img src="share.png" /></div>',
        enableHover: false,
        enableTracking: false,
        render: function(api, options){
            $(api.element).on('click', '.twitter', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                api.openPopup('twitter');
            });
            $(api.element).on('click', '.facebook', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                api.openPopup('facebook');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So there's 4 times that html part on my page and I added the .each function trying to solve this but it didn't have any effect. Any hints or advices to solve this?

Here's a fiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/b54sc/

Comment: The Share dialog does not take any additional parameters apart from the URL any more. Title, description, thumbnail are fetched from the URL in the background. So look into Open Graph meta tags if you want to influence those values for your own URLs. http://ogp.me/

Comment: Thanks for directing to the right way @CBroe ! Open Graph would indeed be the best solution, but I'm implementing this to a one-page-site so all the content is on the same page with horizontal and vertical sliders and looks like you can use those meta tags only in the page HEAD and I need four different urls and texts. But I found a solution, that'll work for now. I'll update my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a solutions for this myself. But if there's any other ideas please share them! Thanks to @CBroe for pointing to the right direction.

Best practice would be using Open Graph meta tags but that's not possible for me because my site is one-page-site so all the content is on the same page. And since meta tags need to be in the HEAD of the html this won't suit me because I'd need four different urls and titles.

But while browsing for the meta tags solution I found another fairly easy solution.

So, Sharrre uses Facebook's sharer.php which is already deprecated. Thou it's deprecated it's still available to use and it's quite common because it doesn't require app_id. But it has changed: it doesn't accept the 't' parameter in the url for the title so that's the reason why my data-text wasn't working. And there's a solution.

This is the page I found:
http://ar.zu.my/how-to-really-customize-the-deprecated-facebook-sharer-dot-php/
Changing the url a little bit does the thing. The title part needs to be 'p[title]' instead of just 't'. And there's also other parameters to use.

THE FIX to Sharrre
Sharrre uses the old method which doesn't work anymore and I just changed the popup creation function in the sharrre.js file on line 325.

From

```
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.facebook.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.facebook.url : opt.url))+"&t="+opt.text+"", "", "toolbar=0, status=0, width=900, height=500");
```

To

```
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]="+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.facebook.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.facebook.url : opt.url))+"&p[title]="+opt.text+"", "", "toolbar=0, status=0, width=900, height=500");
```

I don't know how long this solution works because Facebook can change it again anytime but it'll do for now!

Another way would be usign a Facebook dialog but that needs the app_id.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:** I have added title, url in your code

```
$('.share-buttons').each(function() {
    $(this).sharrre({
        share: {
            twitter: true,
            facebook: true
        },
        title: $(this).attr('data-href'),
        url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
        template: '<div class="share-icon-holder"><a href="#" class="facebook"><img src="fb.png" /></a><a href="#" class="twitter"><img src="twitter.png" /></a></div><div class="share-text"><img src="share.png" /></div>',
        enableHover: false,
        enableTracking: false,
        render: function(api, options){
            $(api.element).on('click', '.twitter', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                api.openPopup('twitter');
            });
            $(api.element).on('click', '.facebook', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                api.openPopup('facebook');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't do it, unfortunately, but I found out that it's a fault in Sharrre. Looks like Facebook doesn't accept anymore sharer.php parameters like it used to and Sharrre is using the old method. I'll post the fix to the original post.

Comment: And you had a typo there: title: $(this).attr('data-href'), attr should be data-text :P